# Assign a key value to another key value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning JavaScript and I have come across the `Object.assign()` method but I am not quite sure how to apply it in project.

Here are my examples :

This is the reference array that each new `profiles` array should parse

```
const references = {
    "photos": {
        "paul": {
            "version": {
                "amsterdam": {
                    "image_url": "firstUrl",
                },
                "rotterdam": {
                    "image_url": "secondUrl",
                }
            }
        },
        "mary": {
            "version": {
                "berlin": {
                    "image_url": "thirdUrl",
                }
            }
        },
        "vincent": {
            "version": {
                "london": {
                    "image_url": "fourthUrl",
                },
                "paris": {
                    "image_url": "fifthUrl",
                },
                "prague": {
                    "image_url": "sixthUrl",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what my API request spits out

```
const profiles = {
    "paul": "rotterdam", 
    "vincent": "prague"
}
```

What I'd like to achieve is put the according `image_url` for each version of the photo like this

```
newArray = {
    "paul": "secondUrl", 
    "vincent": "sixthUrl"
}
```

But is it even possible ? Or is it not the purpose of `Object.assign()`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `Object.assingn()` allow you to copy without reference an object in another, it doesn't fit your need here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a new object using `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const references = {"photos": {"paul": {"version": {"amsterdam": {"image_url": "firstUrl",},"rotterdam": {"image_url": "secondUrl",}}},"mary": {"version": {"berlin": {"image_url": "thirdUrl",}}},"vincent": {"version": {"london": {"image_url": "fourthUrl",},"paris": {"image_url": "fifthUrl",},"prague": {"image_url": "sixthUrl",}}}}}

const profiles = {
    "paul": "rotterdam", 
    "vincent": "prague"
}

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(profiles).map(([k, v]) =>
    [k, references.photos[k]?.version?.[v]?.image_url]
));

console.log(result);
```

Alternatively you can use `Object.assign` instead of `Object.fromEntries`, in combination with the spread syntax:

```js
const references = {"photos": {"paul": {"version": {"amsterdam": {"image_url": "firstUrl",},"rotterdam": {"image_url": "secondUrl",}}},"mary": {"version": {"berlin": {"image_url": "thirdUrl",}}},"vincent": {"version": {"london": {"image_url": "fourthUrl",},"paris": {"image_url": "fifthUrl",},"prague": {"image_url": "sixthUrl",}}}}}

const profiles = {
    "paul": "rotterdam", 
    "vincent": "prague"
}

const result = Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(profiles).map(([k, v]) =>
    ({[k]: references.photos[k]?.version?.[v]?.image_url})
));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is just brilliant. Thank you a lot! These complex codes always look like voodoo spells to me before understanding them, I will keep on reading the docs and some day I'll be able to do it too!

Answer (score 1):

First, the data structure you're working with is an `Object`, not an `Array`.

Second, [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) copies values from source objects to a target object, but does't allow for any manipulation of the *structure* in the process. It sounds like you want to use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to obtain a new  Object from your existing one.

```js
const references = { /* full object abbreviated */ };

const profiles = {
    "paul": "rotterdam", 
    "vincent": "prague"
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(profiles).map(([user, version]) => {
        const photos = references.photos[user];
        const imageUrl = photos.version[version].image_url;
        return [user, imageUrl];
    })
);
```